# Using style in StandardStyle xaml from another Style xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a custom Color.xaml as

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyColor1" Color="#7d897d"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyColor2" Color="#078ab4"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And App.xaml as

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <!-- Defines the colors used in the app-->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Color.xaml"/>
                <!-- Styles that define common aspects of the platform look and
                     feel Required by Visual Studio project and item templates-->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="StandardStyles.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                ............
```

In My StandardStyle.xaml I'm not able to use the Color defined in the xaml.

```
<Style x:Key="HeadingTextStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiLight"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MyColor1}"/>
</Style>
```

It gives me an exception when I run the code

```
"Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key MyColor1 [Line: 20 Position: 44]"
```

However I'm able to use this color in the UI xaml files.

Comment: StandardStyle.Xaml is a resource dictionary ? if yes then have you merged your color resources in StandardStyle?

Comment: No I haven't merged it in `StandardStyle.xaml` but in `App.xaml`, and yes `StandardStyle.Xaml` is a resource dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is, include the `Color.xaml` in `StandardStyle.xaml` as

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Color.xaml"/>    
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <!-- your styles here -->

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: can you still see the exception?

Comment: No I'm not getting exception now :)